# Join element between each item of a list - python

Tags: python

I want to join an element in this case it's "*" between each element of the list but not at the first position and not in the last position

How can I do this ?

Code :

```
import math
def decompose(n:int):
    
    factors = []
    
    
    if n < 2:
        return False
    
    for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) +1):
        
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            print(factors)
            
    factors = str(factors)
    
            
    print(f"The decomposition of {number5} in prime factor is" + '*'.join(str(factors)))       
    return True
    
number5 = int(input('Chose a number:'))


print(decompose(number5))
```

it prints this :

```
Decomposition of 45 in prime factor is [*3*,* *5*]
```

But that's not what I want, I want numbers without commas and without the `*` in first and last position

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting that result from your code.

Comment: @ti7 His code *was* putting `*` between each character. We just couldn't see it because of his question formatting. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```py
def decompose(n: int):
    factors = []

    if n < 2:
        return False

    d = 2
    while d <= n:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(str(d))
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(str(n))

    print(f"The decomposition of {number5} in prime factor is " + '*'.join(factors))
    return True


number5 = int(input('Chose a number:'))

print(decompose(number5))
```

What I've changed:

- The algorithm of factorization. Now it counts multiple multipliers.
- `factors` now is a `List[str]`, so `join` could be performed easily.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the problem is and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar clicked `Post Your Answer` occasionally, is it a crime now?

Comment: It works thank you

Answer (score 1):

One good way to return the factors from the method and then iterate the list as string value.

```
import math


def decompose(n: int):
    factors = []
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
    return factors


number5 = int(input('Choose a number:'))
factors = decompose(number5)
print(f"The decomposition of {number5} in prime factor is " + '*'.join(
    [str(i) for i in factors]))
```

Output:

```
Choose a number:45
The decomposition of 45 in prime factor is 3*5
```

Comment: For 125 your code gives 5. 5 != 125.

Comment: For 125 the prime factor is 5. It is correct. But how the OP wants to represent the result using `*` is not in this case. And the question was mainly regarding printing a list of integers as a string value separated by `*`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this, the following explanation is just one way.

In this line:

```
factors = str(factors)
```

You are turning the list itself into a string. You need to turn each item in the list into strings if you want to join them. You can do this by using a list comprehension:

```
factors = [str(x) for x in factors]
```

Then I would change the line where you print the decomposition to this:

```
print(f"The decomposition of {number5} in prime factor is {'*'.join(factors)}.")
```

So with input 45 the output should be (amongst other things) "The decomposition of 45 in prime factor is 3*5".

EDIT: You might want to look at the rest of your code, 3*5 is not the prime decomposition of 45.

Comment: yes it works too